# Selenium Tag h4 is stale

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When i am trying to fetch h4 tag from a website my script throw stale Exception i try multiple approach but not of them is working and my current code is not printing h4 content.

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://magicpin.in/New-Delhi/Paharganj/Restaurant/Eatfit/store/61a193/delivery'

driver.get(url)
delay = 3

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'catalogItemsHolder')))
    articles = element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'article')

    for article in articles:
        try:
            h4_element = article.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'categoryHeading')
            print(h4_element.text)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            print("H4 element is stale, re-fetching articles...")
            element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'catalogItemsHolder')
            articles = element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'article')

except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading Timeout")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

```html
<div class="catalogItemsHolder">
   <article id="Kulcha Burger" class="categoryListing ">
      <h4 class="categoryHeading"> Kulcha Burger </h4>
      <div>
         
      </div>
   </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue you have there is happened, because you don't wait for all articles to be fully rendered.

Instead of waiting for container to be rendered, try to wait for presence for all elements with selector `.catalogItemsHolder article[id]`
and then get from each article `h4` tag.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://magicpin.in/New-Delhi/Paharganj/Restaurant/Eatfit/store/61a193/delivery'

driver.get(url)
delay = 10
articles = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.catalogItemsHolder article[id]')))

for article in articles:
    h4_element = article.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h4')
    print(h4_element.text)
```